# Save dialog box through javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using javascript to open save dialog box

the java script is

function openDialog(path)
{

```
 document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,path);
```

}

In my project, i am creating linkButtons dynamically and attaching this function with linkButton's OnClient Click event at run time.

```
            LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
            linkButton.OnClientClick = "openDialog("+file.ToString()+")";
```

where "file" contains the path of the file which has to be saved.

But i am getting a javascript error as

"Expected ")" "

can anyone help me in what i am doing wrong in this.

I have N number of dynamically created linkButtons and i am associating each linkButton with different file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not quoting your string so it renders as:

```
openDialog(someFileName.ext);
```

which is not valid JavaScript. Change your C# code to read:

```
linkButton.OnClientClick = "openDialog('"+file.ToString()+"')";
```

This will render to the browser as:

```
openDialog('someFileName.ext');
```

which is valid JavaScript.